# C++ std::add_const not working correctly?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I tried following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
int main() { 
    std::cout << std::is_const<std::add_const<int*&>::type>::value;
}
```

and the output is 0. Is this correct behaviour?

Comment: Yes. C++ is the antithesis of Python's "principle of least astonishment".

Comment: You didn't bother to simply read the documentation. -1

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Given that there's no such thing as a `const`-qualified reference (as opposed to a reference to `const`) in C++, what would you expect the "least surpring" result to be? A compilation error? While maybe less surprising, it would be *much* less useable.

Comment: @Angew: Sound logical, right? Of course. That doesn't mean it's not astounding. Everything has a reason in C++: efficiency, feasibility, readability, interoperability, platform independece, compatibility with other features, or some historical legacy. *If you know the rules, nothing is surprising...* In this case the right naming would be something like `add_const_if_possible`, but, hey I almost forgot it, we also like conciseness.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Perhaps the expectation is also that the `const` should be applied to the referenced type, i.e. it should become `int* const &`. But then again, if you need stuff like `std::add_const` or `std::is_const`, then you are probably familiar with those rules anyway. It's not something a beginner would use, or need.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: As I said, if you know the rules it's *perfectly logical*. But without knowing the rules it goes totally against your *intuition*. The great thing about some languages like python is that with a handful of rules you can follow your intuition and you're going to be almost always right. With C++ OTOH, ... oh god, let's just not go there...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Good point with `add_const_if_possible`; I wouldn't actually mind that name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

References cannot be `const`-qualified, so `std::add_const` is a no-op for reference types.

It makes sense when you think about it (and [is clearly stated in standard library reference material](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv)), but is potentially surprising at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

`std::add_const` does not quite do what you think it does:

> **If T is a reference**, function, or top-level const-qualified type, **then type
>   shall name the same type as T**, otherwise T const.

(From 20.10.7.1 Const-volatile modifications Table 52 in N4140, emphasis mine)

As you can see, `std::add_const` does not add a `const` for reference types.

But what would a constant reference be in the first place, they are immutable anyways. (Not to be confused with reference to `const` vs. reference to non-`const`.)

Answer (score 0):

From the `std::add_const` documentation :

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv

> Provides the member typedef type which is the same as T, except it has
>   a cv-qualifier added (unless T is a function, **a reference**, or already
>   has this cv-qualifier)

Answer (score 0):

If we check the cpprefernece documentation for [std::add_const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv) we see it says:

> Provides the member typedef type which is the same as T, except it has a cv-qualifier added (**unless T is a function, a reference, or already has this cv-qualifier**)

this is consistent with the draft C++ standard section 20.10.7.1 Const-volatile modifications which says the following for `add_const`:

> If T is a reference, function, or top-level const-qualified type, then type
>   shall name the same type as T, otherwise T const.